# Getting full url not working when url contains #

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url, twitch

Hello stack overflow peeps,

Having a bit of an issue implementing an oAuth system.

```
//https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/authentication.md
public ActionResult AuthorizeTwitch(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    var twitchBridge = new TwitchBridge();
    var codes = Request.Params.GetValues("code");
    var token = Request.Params.GetValues("access_token");

    // stage 1 Initial Handshake
    if (codes == null && token == null) {
        return Redirect(twitchBridge.AuthorizeUrl());
    }
    // stage 2 We have a code so we are at stage two request the token
    else if (codes != null) {
        return Redirect(twitchBridge.RetrieveToken(codes[0]));
    }

    // SAVE OAUTH STUFF DOWN HERE.
    // THEN REDIRECT
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

The above action seems to work however when for stages 1 and 2 but when I get a response form stage 2 I get redirected to a URL that looks like.

```
http://localhost:58434/Home/AuthorizeTwitch#access_token=anaccesstoken&scope=user_read
```

This hits my action but I cant access the value for access_token. I can access Request.Url.OriginalString but the return string looks like.

```
http://localhost:58434/Home/AuthorizeTwitch
```

Debugging and looking into the request object and the URL object nothing seems to have stored anything from the # onwards. I suspect this has something to do with the routes setup for my site.

The relevant route that is being hit is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default2",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Can any one see what i'm doing wrong?

In case it is something to do with my actually request to twitch this is how im building the url.

```
public string AuthorizeUrl() {
    return string.Format(
        "{0}{1}?response_type=code&client_id={2}&redirect_uri={3}&scope={4}",
        TwitchUrlBase,
        TwitchAuthorizeMethod,
        ClientId,
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TwitchAuthorizeRedirectURL),
        TwitchAuthorizeScope
    );
}

public string RetrieveToken(string code) {
    return string.Format(
        "{0}{1}?response_type=token&client_id={2}&client_secret={3}grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={4}&scope={5}",
        TwitchUrlBase,
        TwitchAuthorizeMethod,
        ClientId,
        ClientSecret,
        HttpUtility.UrlEncode(TwitchAuthorizeRedirectURL),
        TwitchAuthorizeScope
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fragment](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not supposed to be sent by the client to the server, so it makes sense that it's not there.  Did you mean to send a query?

Comment: Well the url comes from twitch the response to my retrieval of the token. It did seem strange to me that it came back as # where a ? would make about a billion times more sense but i figure the server should still get the whole url so i should be able to see it the request.

Comment: Was there some configuration telling Twitch what URL to go to?  Could that require a trailing '?' perhaps?

Comment: Appending ? to the redirect url results in the same outcome :(

Comment: I'm not very familiar with oAuth...is RetrieveToken supposed to actually cause a redirect, or is it just returning parameters that way.

Comment: It looks like if you just parse the response from that function with a URL parser, you may have what you need right there.

Comment: Ah i think you have hit the nail on the head stage two is meant to be server -> twitch not client -> twitch i think your correct.

Comment: Yep changing it to post to the server was correct for stage 2. Thanks for getting me on the correct path.